# Android Activity Screen Orientation onResume

Tags: android, screen, orientation

I've got a rather simple app, the main **LinearLayout** has its orientation set to horizontal and contains a few views. The activity `screenOrientation` is set to landscape. Starting it everything looks OK. If I leave my phone for a while & let the screen lock thats when I get problems. When I swipe the screen lock off, the activity reappears but is showing in portrait mode with all the views in the `LinearLayout` showing all squashed up together. If I do nothing at all then after 1 or 2 seconds the app switched back to landscape & lays out everything correctly.

How can I stop this happening ? I thought if I set the activity `screenOrientation` to landscape it would stay in landscape. Is this because I am doing something wrong in my code, or is it a bug in Android ? I'm using Android 2.2.1 on my phone.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a bug in android as far as i know. Please paste some code related to the issue.

Comment: trapped this with LogCat 06-22 14:24:07.026: INFO/HtcLockScreen(9244): onOrientationChange: inPortrait=false, mCreatedInPortrait=false
06-22 14:24:07.886: INFO/HtcLockScreen(9244): onOrientationChange: inPortrait=true, mCreatedInPortrait=true